# Simple probability

Tags: probability

If the probability of one out of $6$ light failing is $0.05$. What is the probability that $4$ lights fail at some point ?
My approach is $(0.05^4)$ x $(0.95^2)$
Is it correct?
Can this be solved using Combinatorics?

Comment: The meaning of "one out of 6 failing" is very unclear. Does it mean _exactly_ one of the six failing, _at least_ one of the six failing, or something else?.

Comment: @AmitPathak can you clarify what you meant? 1. The probability of a bulb failing independent of others is 0.05. 2. Probability of exactly one bulb failing out of total six is 0.05. Or something else?

Comment: Actually it is a little tricky question, got the answer from my professor ! The correct interpretation of this problem is - Probability of exactly one bulb failing out of total six is 0.05 @gunes

Comment: In that case there are two answers to the question as I laid out in my comment

Comment: I have also pinned my solution to this question. Apologies for the confusion! @gunes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If bulbs are assumed independent, and additionally we leave the time dimension out of the question, number of bulbs that'll fail, say $X$, is Binomial $(n=6,p=0.05)$ and your answer is $$P(X=4)={6\choose 4}0.05^40.95^2$$

**Update**: Based on your clarification on the comments under the OP, we'd have the following relation:

$$p(1-p)^5=0.05/6$$ which has two [possible](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20p*%281-p%29%5E5%20%3D%200.05%2F6) solutions. And, for each one, the asked probability, which is
$${6\choose 4}p^4(1-p)^2$$ has **different** values. So, there are two answers to your question. Approximately, they are $8.46e-8$ and $0.293$.

Comment: I disagree with this answer and the claim that the bulbs fail (independently of each other) with probability $p = 0.05$. The OP's statement "one out of 6 fail" suggests that we are being told that the probability that exactly one of the 6 has failed is $0.05$ and so if we assume independent faliures with probability $p$, then we are have is $\binom{6}{1}p(1-p)^5 = 0.05$ which we need to solve for $p$ before using $\binom{6}{4}p^4(1-p)^2$

Comment: @DilipSarwate you're right, the OP needs rewording. In this way, there are two possible $p$'s, and therefore there are two possible outcomes of the question being asked. See: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+p*%281-p%29%5E5+%3D+0.05%2F6 . I believe it's the simpler one.

Comment: @gunes For this particular question, your answer fails as you already know the reason